# saving Android Intent data to image File

Tags: android, image-processing, android-intent, android-camera

I'm getting data over Intent(onActivityResult) from a crop image method and saving it in a file.

My challenge is that the file(image) I'm getting is reduced to ~50KB and which is not acceptable as the image has to be ~500KB for use.

is there any parameters I can change with crop intent to get a better image quality.

```
CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

Another problem is I'm converting the intent data into Bitmap and then saving it.

Is there any method by which I can directly save the Intent data to a file.

My save image code is -

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ListView1", "Image view set exception: "+ e.toString());
            }

            try {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/NVoids/toServer.jpeg");
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024 * 8);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ListView1", "Save to file exception: "+ e.toString());
            }
```

My crop image function is -

```
public void ImageCropFunction() {
    // Image Crop Code
    try {
        try {
            Log.d("ListView1", "ImageUri: " + imageUri.toString()); } catch ( Exception e) {  Log.d("ListView1", "ImageUri exception: " + e.toString());  }
        CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        CropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
        CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 50000);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 50000);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
        CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("ListView1", "ImageCropFunction Activity Not Found exception: " + e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ListView1", "ImageCropFunction exception: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

In case you want to see the whole activity file [here it is](https://pastebin.com/uqc8ZWSQ) and the [layout file](https://pastebin.com/ARV29F9U)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Intent property to specify the size of the resulting image in bytes, only "outputX" and "outputY" to control the width and height, and related items like "scale", "aspectX", and "aspectY" that you are already using.

However, you may be getting a smaller image than the crop function is actually producing because, as the documentation says (emphasis mine),

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image
> will be written. **If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small**
> **sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field.** This is
> useful for applications that only need a small image. If the
> EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to
> the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

This is also key to the answer to your second problem.
You should not have to write the image yourself - you should put the location for the file to be writing in EXTRA_OUTPUT of the intent, and let the code that does the cropping write the file.

TLDR; put the destination for the file int the EXTRA_OUTPUT of the intent, and the file will be written for you, and will probably be larger than what gets returned if you don't do this.